# How do I populate a listView that has two columns, given a LINQ query?

Tags: c#, linq, listview

I have a folder with files (the files in this folder can variate in number):

XXX_1.jpg
XXX_2.jpg
ZZZ_1.jpg
ZZZ_2.jpg
BBB_1.jpg
YYY_1.jpg

I want to populate a listView that has two columns: Name & Count.

In this example, the listView should look like this:

XXX 2
ZZZ 2
BBB 1
YYY 1

How would I go about constructing a LINQ query to separate name & count from the items in the folder and then populate the listView with the name of the file + how many times its in the directory?

Here's how I started:

```
IEnumerable<string[]> groups = originalFiles
                                .GroupBy(policyName => policyName.Split('_')[0])
                                .Select(g => g.ToArray());

                foreach (var group in groups)
                {
                    //add group name + count in listView
                }
```

I need to add Count() somewhere there but I'm not really sure.

Comment: We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question- if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Comment: How can you have 2 files with the same name in a single folder?

Comment: my appologies. I fixed the file names

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
var groups = orignalFiles.GroupBy(o => o.Split('_')[0])
                       .Select(o => new { 
                                           Name = o.FirstOrDefault().Split('_')[0], 
                                           Total = o.Count() 
                                        });
```

Good Luck !!

Comment: seems like this worked but how do I go about extracting the name and total from "var groups?" for example, how would i go about doing MessageBox.Show(Name + " " +  Count.ToString()); ???

Comment: @Testifier: what about `foreach(var item in groups){MessageBox.Show(item.Name, item.Count.ToString()); }`?

Comment: thanks naveen. that worked :) I'm still new to this LINQ stuff and the syntax is very confusing :(